# Why I am unable to import trl package in Jupyter?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-trainer, nltk-trainer

I am trying to import `SFTTrainer` from `trl` package. I am getting the error message - `ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions' (D:\...\..\)`. **I am able to do it perfectly well in Google Colab, no issues**. Why is this? How can I import on my local PC/ `Jupyter`?

I installed the `trl` package and tried importing `SFFTrainer` using:

```
!pip install trl
from trl import SFTTrainer
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `typing-extensions`, that did not work. I uninstalled `trl` and tried installing it from `Anaconda powershell prompt` and I tried a few other installations, updates and uninstallations. I even tried importing `trl` from `github` and then load. None of them is working.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you running it in your local machine or in a cloud provider? Ex: Databricks, Google Colab etc. Which is your Python version and openai, typing_extensions, and trl version?

Comment: Just a note on your line in the code block that says, "!pip install trl". You should no longer be using exclamation points in conjunction with install commands for `pip` or `conda`. The magic pip install commands were added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. So in this example, you have run `%pip install trl` in a cell. Then restarted the kernel. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands that ...

Comment: <continued> are current best practice. And they universally work now. Even in JupyterLite and Google Colab now. Take anything you come across suggesting an exclamation point in conjunction with an install command with a grain of salt as the advice may be outdated and not following current best practices. You'll have a better experience going forward if you adopt it now.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Seems a version incompatibility problem between typing_extensions and other packages.

## Solution

I tested it with Python 3.10 and some pinned versions of the following packages, and it should work for you also.

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.10
conda activate my_env
pip install openai==1.8.0 typing_extensions==0.4.7 trl
```

Those packages usually cause dependency errors, so this should fix your current problem and future ones.

## Extra Ball

There is a similar issue in the `openai` repository: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/751